# What happened to the Separatist Senate at the end of the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In the *Star Wars* movies, we see that there is really just the Separatist Council lead by various ‘bad guys’ who are then eliminated by Darth Vader.  However, in the *Clone Wars* series, we see that there is actually a fully fledged Senate populated by member worlds and Senators who have left the Republic.  What happened to them at the end of the war?  Were they told to surrender unconditionally since their droids were no longer functional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unknown what became of the Separatist Senate in canon. However, in Legends, after the Separatist Council was executed on Mustafar, and Dooku and Grievous were killed, the Separatists surrendered and their Senate was dissolved. A signal was sent from Mustafar by Darth Vader that shut down the Separatist Army. This all comes from the [Legends Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Separatist_Parliament).